# SFML2 render to texture anti-aliasing not working

Tags: opengl, textures, sfml, antialiasing

Im trying to render an anti-aliased opengl scene to texture using the lastest sfml 2. But it wont anti-alias.

I came across this post http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=3622.0 and it made me think it's not implemented.

Is it not implemented?

Comment: Why don't you ask on the official forum directly? The author of SFML is reading nearly every single post and mostly answers questions within one or two hours.

Comment: I always found stackoverflow to be a great site. So this time I choose to ask my question here. Just to start my stackoverflow account of.

Comment: So you got a question about the implementation of a library, but instead of asking the developer of the library, you rather ask random people, if they know how SFML got implemented?